# How do I route my application back to the home page from a form using React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs, forms, react-props

I'm fairly new to React and Rails, and I'm stuck at a point where I can't figure out how to use React-Router to move back to my main application "/" after a successful form submission. I'm currently trying to use the withRouter and props.history.push methods. Here are snippets of the relevant code.

App.js:

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import { BrowserRouter as Router, Route } from 'react-router-dom';
import axios from 'axios';

import './App.css';
import Note from '../Note';
import NoteEdit from '../NoteEdit';

class App extends Component {
  constructor(props) {
   super(props)

  this.state = {
   note: ""
  }
 }


 componentDidMount = () => {
  this.getNote();
  this.interval = setInterval(() => {
   this.getNote();
  }, 5000);
 }

 getNote = () => {
  // Axios Get Request
 }

handleChange = (event) => {
 // Controlled Form Logic
 this.setState({note: event.target.value})
}

handleSubmit = (event) => {
 event.preventDefault();
 axios.put('http://localhost:3001/notes/1', {
  text: this.state.note
 })
 .then(response => {
  console.log(response);
 })
 .catch(error => {
  console.log(error)
 });
 this.props.history.push("/");
}

render() {
 return (
  <Router>
    <div className="App">
      <Route exact path="/" render={props =>
        (<Note {...props} note={this.state.note}/>)
      }/>
      <Route path="/edit" render={props =>
        (<NoteEdit {...props} note={this.state.note} handleSubmit={this.handleSubmit} handleChange={this.handleChange}/>)
      }/>
    </div>
  </Router>
 )
 }
}

export default App;
```

Full "NoteEdit.js" Child Component

```
import React, { Component } from 'react';
import './NoteEdit.css';
import { withRouter } from 'react-router-dom';

class NoteEdit extends Component {

 render() {
 return (
  <div className="NoteEdit">
    <form onSubmit={this.props.handleSubmit}>
      <textarea className="text_area" type="text" defaultValue={this.props.note} onChange={this.props.handleChange}/>
      <input type="submit" value="Save"/>
    </form>
  </div>
)}}

export default withRouter(NoteEdit);
```

The current error is that props is undefined in history.props. Am I supposed to bind this somewhere? I tried binding it in my App.js and on the Submit method when called in my child component.

I updated it to include the whole App.js file to better see what is going on, commenting out what seemed unnecessary.

Comment: Is there any reason `handleSubmit` can't live in `NoteEdit.js`?

Comment: I guess in my thinking since it deals with this.state which is in App.js, It should live in App.js and be passed as a prop.

Comment: State should be at the highest level possible and your `handleChange` method should be there too. I don't think it would cause much of an issue to have the `handleSubmit` method in your `NoteEdit` component. `App` is out of the scope of `Router` so you won't be able to access the history props there.

Comment: Hm alright I'll give that a try. Made me think that it could make sense to create another layer in between App.js and NoteEdit.js, so that there would be a Router Nested in a Router?

Comment: You should only have one `Router` in your application.

Comment: Okay I'll avoid that then. The reason handleSubmit lives in app.js is because I was trying to send this.state.note as my put request, which lives in app.js. Should I be passing the state in as a prop to NoteEdit, and from there making the put request?

Comment: That should work.

Comment: Great, Thanks! Got it working just like you said.

Answer (score 1):

I don't know the export method of App.js, but if the component is not exported using `withRouter`, the history props probably won't be available.

An easy solution could be to just use `window.location = '/';` instead of `history.push()`.

Comment: I added the whole App.js, hopefully that makes it more clear what my intentions are. window.location does work but I was hoping to keep it as 'one-page application' as possible. I figured there must be a solution that I'm just not seeing. Thank you though!

Answer (score 0):

Thanks @seanulus for the correct way to approach this.

my handleSubmit function just needed to live in the NoteEdit.js component, and use the prop 'note' (Which comes from App.js state) as the axios requests body.

Works like a charm!